# provide index on click with knockout repeat

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to provide a number of clicked link to click handler.
For some reason it provides the whole knockout model, instead of the $index. Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/hfWs8/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `.bind` determines what `this` will be in the handler.  So, you can either pass `$index` as the second argument or operate on `this` in your handler with your current code.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Ff9rh/